# How do I test a string with words in every order

Tags: python-2.7

i am trying to make an if statement but i realized that i need to test the string with the words in every possible arrangement. so how might I go about this.

here is my code

```
string = ("red blue black")

if string == "red blue black":
    print("cool")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to create an `if` statement that creates all arrangements of your `string` variable, then test if your "string" is in any of those arrangements.

All arrangements of a list would be the "permutations", so you can use permutation of [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools

string = ("red blue black")

all_arrangements = list(itertools.permutations(string.split()))

if string in [' '.join(i) for i in all_arrangements]:
    print "cool"
```

Since the arrangements are generated based on your string, you can expect your if statement will be satisfied, and "cool" will always be printed, unless you further change the logic of the `if` statement.

To better explain what's going on in the code above, you could replace the above `if` statement block with the following code, and confirm which arrangement of your string matches:

```
print "checking for ", string

for arrangement in all_arrangements:
    if string == ' '.join(arrangement):
        print arrangement , "cool"
    else:
        print arrangement
```

output:

```
checking for  red blue black
('red', 'blue', 'black') cool
('red', 'black', 'blue')
('blue', 'red', 'black')
('blue', 'black', 'red')
('black', 'red', 'blue')
('black', 'blue', 'red')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: IIRC `string` isn't a keyword/built-in, whereas `str` is a built-in.

Comment: @jackyd, glad to hear it works for you, please consider upvoting my answer and accepting it using the green checkmark, thanks!